# Configuration Manager has no Intellisense

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configurationmanager

`ConfigurationManager` is not displaying in intellisense ... can anybody help?

Answer (score 5):

Your C# project needs to reference the `System.Configuration` framework assembly and you need to import this namespace `using System.Configuration` ... if you are looking for the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class.